# Bootstrap column content image responsiveness

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I've pretty much resolved my issue regarding large images but I"m still having problems with smaller images fitting into a larger space.

Basically, I made a CMS for a user who needed templates with different bootstrap columns as content areas. Currently he's dragging images into these areas, driven by TinyMCE editors, and saving them as HTML that displays on large screens (around 70")

So dragging a huge image (several thousand pixels) seems to scale down and work nicely, but he's currently trying to add an image of the dimensions below and when it shows on the large screens it fits very small on the screen (obviously due to the smaller dimensions)

Is there a way to modify this so that smaller images can grow/expand to fit responsively into the full column area?

```css
<style type="text/css">
      html,
      body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
      }

      iframe{
      height:100% !important;
      width:100% !important;
      }

      .middle p{
      max-height:100%;
      margin-bottom:0;     
      display: flex
      }

      img {
      object-fit: scale-down;
      width: 100%; 
      height:100%;
      margin:0 auto;
      }
      #leftContent{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:100%;
      }
      #leftContent img{
          object-fit: contain;
      }
      .leftContent{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
      }
      .leftContent> img{
        min-width:100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
      #rightContent{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:100%;
      }
      #rightContent img{
          object-fit: contain;
      }
      .rightContent{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
      }
      .rightContent> img{
        min-width:100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
      /*END EDITOR RESPONSIVE STYLES*/



      .my-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width:100vw;
      }

      .my-container .top.row, 
      .my-container .row.bottom {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
      .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
      background-color: #778899  ;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      }

      .my-container>.middle {
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding:30px;
      /*background-image: url('images/bg_green.svg');*/
      background-size: cover;
      }

      .my-container>.middle>* {
      }

      </style>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid my-container d-flex h-100">
        <div class="row top">
          <h2>Top Row</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
          <!-- Half Page Divs -->
          <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn " id="leftColumn" style="align-items: center;">  
              <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" margin:auto; ">  
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/715x938 "> 
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn" id="rightColumn"> 
            <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" >
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/715x938 "> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Half Page Divs -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Row Middle -->

        <div class="row bottom">
            <h2>Bottom Row</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve from your example because it looks like a nice layout. But, a class you can use is `img-fluid`. This will make the image scale with the parent element.

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```